Pull request proposed for pandas overflow with timestamp normalize
Looking at this issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/60583
My understanding is that the bug is due to the code logic described in timestamps.pyx.
The first option that I considered was modifying normalize in timestamps.pyx. The second option that I considered was modifying normalize_i8_stamp() in timestamps.pyx, and also updating normalize_i8_stamp() in timestamps.pxd to update the normalize_i8_stamp() declaration to match the new signature.
datetimes.py would not be modified because my understanding is that this overflow issue is not present in datetimes.
My proposed change is shown below:
cdef:
        local_val = self._maybe_convert_value_to_local()
        int64_t normalized
        int64_t ppd = periods_per_day(self._creso)
        _Timestamp ts

    # Check for potential overflow before normalization
    if local_val < INT64_MIN or local_val > INT64_MAX:
        raise OutOfBoundsDatetime(
            f"Cannot normalize Timestamp {self} without overflow"
        )

    normalized = normalize_i8_stamp(local_val, ppd)
    
    # Additional overflow check after normalization
    if normalized < INT64_MIN or normalized > INT64_MAX:
        raise OutOfBoundsDatetime(
            f"Normalization of {self} would cause an overflow"
        )

    ts = type(self)._from_value_and_reso(normalized, reso=self._creso, tz=None)
    return ts.tz_localize(self.tzinfo)

